# Can a subset ever be considered as a member/element of its superset under certain conditions?

Tags: terminology, computer-science

For example:

Let $\mathrm{S}$ be a 2x2 square matrix. Each element in $\mathrm{S}$, denoted by the term $\mathrm{sector_{\alpha \beta}}$, is itself a set of non-numerical objects (a custom software type). Let us use letters to represent these objects (whose contents/value is fixed).

$$\mathrm{S} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{x} & \mathrm{a,b,c} \\
\mathrm{y} & \mathrm{z} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So, $\ \mathrm{sector_{11}} =  \mathrm{\{x\}}$,  $\ \mathrm{sector_{12}} =  \mathrm{\{a,b,c\}}$, $\ \mathrm{sector_{21}} =  \mathrm{\{y\}}$,  $\ \mathrm{sector_{22}} =  \mathrm{\{z\}}$

(Okay, I know I could have just used $\ \mathrm{S_{\alpha \beta}}\ $ instead of $\  \mathrm{sector_{\alpha \beta}}\ $ but indulge me...)

Is a $\ \mathrm{sector}\ $ a subset of $\ \mathrm{S}\ $  or an element of $\ \mathrm{S}$ ? I suppose it depends on whether you can consider a matrix a special sort of set, or an object type only? I mean, $\mathrm{S}$ is itself a subset of $\mathbb{M_n}$

This is just a fun question for my own curiosity, because I actually get off on the terminology of mathematics. It's a sickness I am sure at least some of you share with me! (It occurred as I am in the middle of formulating a description of a solution using arrays within arrays whose elements are slices of other, larger arrays! Fun!)

P.S. What other contexts might such an enjoyable ambiguity of membership exist? If there even is any ambiguity at all, I could just be completely misconceiving this whole thing...

Comment: I'm not sure why `set-theory` was removed from the tags of my post, when it is clearly about sets...

Comment: Not every question about sets is a question in set theory.

Comment: Awww... Set Police! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In set theory, a set $x$ is *transitive* if for all $y$, if $y\in x$ then $y\subseteq x$. The (von Neumann) *ordinals* are defined to be the transitive sets that are well-ordered by $\in$. Thus the "$<$" relation between ordinals is simply $\in$. If $\alpha, \beta$ are ordinals with $\alpha\in \beta$, then $\alpha \subseteq \beta$. So any ordinal is a fine example of a superset, some of whose subsets are also members (namely, every smaller ordinal is both a member and a subset).

Comment: That was so beautiful... but could you add an addendum which 'dumbs it down' a little for me? Meanwhile, I will look up what an *ordinal* is...! EDIT: Oh wow, what a lovely concept, and actually quite helpful for my field... cool!

Comment: I can try, ... but first, let me know when you've looked up *ordinals* :) I'm not sure which part goes too fast for ya, so you'll have to tell me.

Comment: "Ordinal numbers are thus the 'labels' needed to arrange infinite collections of objects in order" – so could we consider a *sector* as I used it in my question kind of analogous to this context? Is 'element/member' – no MathJax in comments :( – effectively a relation (between objects and/or collections) in the way you describe it in your answer?

Comment: No, you can do MathJax in comments. $\in$ is a relation between sets, yes — at least, any restriction of it to a set-sized collection is. (This is a technicality: there's no one collection of all $(x,y)$ such that $x\in y$, because that's "too big" to be a set: it's a "proper class".) Your "sectors" are more like $\in$ than like $\subseteq$, I'd say. But in many discussions of matrices it's useful to treat, say, the upper left $n\times n$ submatrix of an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix, and then "is a submatrix of" is usually more like $\subseteq$.

Comment: The definition of ordinal which my answer assumes is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals. The whole article looks good.

Comment: Yep that's what I was referring to also re: ordinals. I get it now, thanks for answering!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your software.